# C# Generic Extension Method Boxing Conversion Issue

Tags: c#, generics, boxing

I'm working on migrating/rewriting some Java generics in C#. I'm getting an error that I don't understand.

(This is partially an experiment based on composition over inheritance to limit bloat for child-classes that don't need some functionality, but it's also just an experiment to better understand C# generics.)

Note: the actual child-class implementations actually work like I expect, it's just the extension method that isn't compiling.

A parent class:

```
public abstract class PageObject<T> where T : PageObject<T>
{

    protected IWebDriver WebDriver => ServiceLocator.GetWebDriver();

    public PageObject()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(WebDriver, this);
    }

    // ... more stuff, but the constructor is the important thing that keeps
    // me using an abstract parent class. There are some abstract methods
    // that return T so the child classes can return "this" in a fluent api.
}
```

An interface:

```
public interface IHasCustomLoadCondition<T> where T : PageObject<T>
{
    bool IsLoaded();
}
```

and an extension method, this is where the error is occuring:

```
public static T WaitForCustomPageLoad<T>(this T page) where T : IHasCustomLoadCondition<T>
{
    wait.Until<bool>((d) =>
    {
        return page.IsLoaded();
    });
    return page;
}
```

The error message:

```
The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
'IHasCustomLoadCondition<T>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion
from 'T' to 'PageObject<T>'.
```

Comment: `public abstract class PageObject<T> where T : PageObject<T>` .  So this means your class is of type `PageObject<PageObject<T>> `. Shouldn't `T` in this case be class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have this declaration:

```
public interface IHasCustomLoadCondition<T> where T : PageObject<T>
                                            ^---------------------^
```

You must ensure you also carry this constraint into derived interfaces, implementing classes and methods that are also generic on the same `T`, so this method:

```
public static T WaitForCustomPageLoad<T>(this T page) where T : IHasCustomLoadCondition<T>
```

Must also have this constraint:

```
public static T WaitForCustomPageLoad<T>(this T page)
    where T : PageObject<T>, IHasCustomLoadCondition<T>
```

Basically:

```
public static T WaitForCustomPageLoad<T>(this T page) where T : IHasCustomLoadCondition<T>
                                      ^                                                 ^
                                      |                                                 |
                                      +-------- constraints must be compatible ---------+
```

Comment: That was the ticket! I thought the constraint would have been implicit (that, and I didn't know I could do both). Thanks!

Comment: @BCqrstoO - Eric Lippert wrote a good post about [why are generic constraints not inherited](https://ericlippert.com/2013/07/15/why-are-generic-constraints-not-inherited/)

Answer (score 0):

You have unclear generic type constraints both on interface and method.

```
public interface IHasCustomLoadCondition<T> where T : PageObject<T>
```

It means, that it could be smth like this, as you constrainted the generic type argument of `PageObject` to the same class:

```
public TestClass : IHasCustomLoadCondition<PageObject<PageObject<PageObject...
```

If it is not an error, then you should modify your method declaration in the following manner:

```
public static T WaitForCustomPageLoad<T, T1>(this T page) 
where T : IHasCustomLoadCondition<T1>
where T1 : PageObject<T1>
```

As in the original source you constraints mean "Generic type argument should be `IHasCustomLoadCondition<IHasCustomLoadCondition<IHasCustomLoadCondition...` "

But constraint for interface mean that generic type argument for `IHasCustomLoadCondition` should be `PageObject`, but `PageObject` does not implement `IHasCustomLoadCondition`.

I hope, it is understandable explanation.